# undefined control sequence when compiling on Ubuntu (no problem with OSX)

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to compile my CV latex file which works fine with a slightly out of date version of Mac OSX. My new computer is running Ubuntu 13.10 with all of the latest updates and all of the Latex packages installed that I can think of. This is the error message I get when I use pdflatex

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
\cftdotfill #1->\def \@tempa 
                             {#1}\def \@tempb {\cftnodots }\ifx \@tempa \@te...
l.102 ...ada}{Waterloo}{2011}
```

When I try to compile using Kile (the KDE Latex editor) the editor seems to be indicating that the problem is coming from the line:

```
\ressubheading{Math}{Waterloo}{University}{2011}
```

where ressubheading is defined by

```
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
```

I haven't changed anything about the file between being able to compile on OSX and not being able to compile it on Ubuntu. Worst case is that I have to redo my CV is a template that works with Ubuntu but I would really like to avoid that.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This sounds like a version issue. Could you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the results `File list` from the `.log` into the question: one list for each operating system would be best.

Comment: [This answer][1] saved the same problem for me (in particular, \usepackage{array}).


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131568